# Why does this bit count function fail after 32 bits

Tags: javascript, integer, numbers

For the following code snippet:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
  let count = 0
  const num = Math.pow(2, i) - 1
  let n = num
  while (n > 0) {
    n = n & (n - 1)
    count++
  }
  console.log(`The binary representation of the number 2^${i}-1 contains ${count} '1', binary: ${num.toString(2)}`)
}
```

The output is:

- if `0 <= i <= 31` then `count` equal to `i` which is correct
- if `32 <= i` then count equal to `1`. This is clearly wrong

---

1. Why is count equal to 1 when `i` is `[32, +∞]`?
2. Why is the `num.toString(2)` always wrong when `i` is greater than 32 ?

> example: `i` is `54` `The binary representation of the number 2^54-1 contains 1 '1', binary: 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) on MDN

Comment: when i paste this into console `count` is always `1`  if `i>32` so i cant verify your second assumption

Comment: @johnSmith Sorry,my mistakes. It have been corrected.

Answer (score 3):

When using bitwise operators in JavaScript, the

> ... operands are converted to thirty-two-bit integers and expressed by
> a series of bits (zeros and ones). Numbers with more than 32 bits get
> their most significant bits discarded.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).

So when using the `&` operator, the values up to 2**32 - 1 will produce the correct result and values after it will produce unexpected results since the result of `Math.pow(2, i) - 1` is chopped off during `&` operation.

Answer (score 0):

While the specification defines the Number type as:

> double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754-2019 values

https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type

In reality, different js engines will generally treat integers differently.

For example V8, Chrome's JS engine will switch the underlying datatype as needed from more simple to more complex:

> ECMAScript standardizes numbers as 64-bit floating-point values, also known as double precision floating-point or Float64. However, that doesn’t mean that JavaScript engines store numbers in Float64 representation all the time — doing so would be terribly inefficient! Engines can choose other internal representations, as long as the observable behavior matches Float64 exactly.
>
> Most numbers in real-world JavaScript applications happen to be valid ECMAScript array indices, i.e. integer values in the range from 0 to 2³²−2.
>
> JavaScript engines can choose an optimal in-memory representation for such numbers to optimize code that accesses array elements by index. For the processor to do the memory access operation, the array index must be available in two’s complement. Representing array indices as Float64 instead would be wasteful, as the engine would then have to convert back and forth between Float64 and two’s complement every time someone accesses an array element.
>
> The 32-bit two’s complement representation is not just useful for array operations. In general, processors execute integer operations much faster than floating-point operations

That means that while you are using simple integers, V8 will store them as a [two’s complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) 32-bit number

That said, for the behaviour you are seeing in your code example, the answer by Salman A addresses that better than I can.

Comment: That is incorrect.

Comment: @SalmanA Can you elaborate?

Comment: Look at my answer. It has nothing to do with float. The `&` operator is the problem. Also for the main part of the answer you just say _no idea_ and _I assume_.

Comment: The question is quite literally "How are integers stored in javascript" The majority of my answer addresses that. Your answer is a good explanation of why they are seeing a specific behaviour. I'll edit my answer to point to yours for the bitwise part